# Send an xls file in kdb q using sendmail functionality

Tags: email, kdb, xls

I have an xls file saved from the table and will want to send the xls file on an email using sendmail functionality.

The xls file is as : (Method 1)

```
xlsFile : `:temp/email.xls 0: .h.edsn `tickets`volumes!(TicketsTable;VolumesTable)

system "echo 'report for today' |sendmail -s '", emailSubject, "' -a '", xlsFilePath, "' ", emailRecipient;
```

But the above shows length error

Method 2:

```
// Define the email recipient
emailRecipient: "recipient@example.com";

// Define the email subject
emailSubject: "Email Subject";

// Define the path to the XLS file
xlsFilePath: `:temp/email.xls;

// Generate the XLS file content
xlsData: .h.edsn[`tickets`volume!(`ticket1`ticket2`ticket3;100 200 150)];

// Save the XLS data to the file
0: xlsFilePath set xlsData;

// Create the email command
emailCommand: "echo 'This is the email body' | sendmail -s '", emailSubject, "' -a '", xlsFilePath, "' ", emailRecipient;

// Send the email using the system command
system emailCommand;

// Remove the temporary XLS file
system "rm ", xlsFilePath;
```

The above still shows length error

Answer (score 1):

Your method 2 file path variable is a symbol. You need to convert it to a string and remove the leading colon before joining it while defining your emailCommand:

```
q)"echo 'This is the email body' | sendmail -s '", emailSubject, "' -a '",(1_string xlsFilePath), "' ", emailRecipient
"echo 'This is the email body' | sendmail -s 'Email Subject' -a 'temp/email.xls' recipient@example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you need to ensure all the items you are appending together are the same datatype. `xlsFilePath` is a symbol, specifically a file path so it starts with `:`. You need to convert to a `string` and remove the `:` with `1_`

```
emailCommand: "echo 'This is the email body' | sendmail -s '", emailSubject, "' -a '",(1_ string xlsFilePath), "' ", emailRecipient;

system "rm ",(1_ string xlsFilePath);
```

Comment: `code
emailCommand : "echo 'This is the email body' | sendmail -s '", emailSubject, "' -a '",(1_ string xlsFilePath), "' ", emailRecipient;
q))system emailCommand
sendmail: invalid option -- 's'
sendmail: invalid option -- 's'
sendmail: fatal: usage: sendmail [options]
'os
  [5]  \echo 'This is the email body' | sendmail -s 'Subject: RFQ Report' -a 'temp/email.xls' To: abc@mail.com 
@rianoc - this shows error

Comment: Have you tested this command in a shell outside q? Sendmail docs do not list `-s` as a valid option
https://linux.die.net/man/8/sendmail.sendmail

Comment: Yes, it does not work outside the q prompt as well.